# Try to setText on onAnimationEnd and to repeat animation but it change the text 2 times

Tags: android, animation, textview, settext

I am trying to make a animation on a textView and to change the content on onAnimationEnd but it change jump one text and take the next one. I don't know if you understand great, my english is not so good.
This is my code:

```
final Integer[][] listeQuestions = new Integer [][]{
                        {R.string.c1}, {R.string.c2}, {R.string.c3}, {R.string.c4}, {R.string.c5}, {R.string.mot1}, {R.string.c6}, {R.string.c7}, {R.string.c8}, {R.string.c9}, {R.string.c10}, {R.string.mot2},
                        {R.string.c11}, {R.string.c12}, {R.string.c13}, {R.string.c14}, {R.string.c15}, {R.string.mot3}, {R.string.c16}, {R.string.c17}, {R.string.c18}, {R.string.c19}, {R.string.c20}, {R.string.mot4},
                        {R.string.c21}, {R.string.c22}, {R.string.c23}, {R.string.c24}, {R.string.c25}, {R.string.mot5}, {R.string.c26}, {R.string.c27}, {R.string.c28}, {R.string.c29}, {R.string.c30}, {R.string.mot6},
                        {R.string.c31}, {R.string.c32}, {R.string.c33}, {R.string.c34}, {R.string.c35}, {R.string.mot7}
                };

boutonResultat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        resultatTexte.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                        resultatTexte.setText(listeQuestions[0][0]);

                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.laps_temps);

                            resultatTexte.startAnimation(animation);


                        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                            Integer curseur=0;

                            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                if(curseur<42) {

                                curseur++;
resultatTexte.setText(listeQuestions[curseur][0]);

                                    animation.setAnimationListener(this);
                                    resultatTexte.startAnimation(animation);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

My animation is simple, it's just a alpha who begin at 0.2 to 1.0 and the duration is 3000.

I tryied a lot of possibilities (change the animation duration, put some elements in onAnimationStart, put a new code to try to block the double, I leaved the setAnimationListener in onAnimationEnd ...) but always the same problem: R.string.c1 appear great and the animation is correct, when it's finish, R.string.c2 appear maybe 0.1seconds and directly appear R.string.c3 and the animation work correctly, and R.string.c4 appear 0.1 seconds and R.string.c5 works great and like this to the end.

Maybe someone already had an equivalent problem and can help me to resolve it.
Thank you and sorry for my english :)

Comment: Do you have a prototype of your animation? I mean proper one, just want to know what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I don' have a prototype, it's my first application and I don't know how to do this. I'm trying to make a list of calcul who appear every 3 seconds, like: R.string.c1 = 4*8, R.string.c2= 9/3, R.string.c3 = 8*8, R.string.c4= 12*3 ...

C1 works great, c2 don't really appear (just a few times, like a flash), c3 works great, c4 like c2. One work and stay 3seconds and the next is a flash (impossible to see it), the problem stay to the end.

I think it's not so difficult to resolve it but I can't get it, I don't understand why "curseur++" and my setText works two time ... I call them one time.